# Unable to get pillars in salt runner

Tags: python, python-3.x, salt-stack, configuration-management

I'm writing a custom runner in saltstack to do some operations on saltmaster. However I'm unable to invoke the pillars within the runner.

The secrets are stored in the pillars referenced against the saltmaster `id` in the pillar top.sls for example

```
prd:
    'my_saltmaster':
        - match: pcre
        - salt_secrets
```

This is what I've tried

```
import salt.runner
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

runner = salt.runner.Runner(__opts__)
secret = runner.cmd(fun='salt.cmd', arg=['pillars.get', 'my_secret'])
log.info(f"my_secret = {secret}")
```

Output

```
my_secret =
```

I've checked the official source code and couldn't find anything resourceful. It would be great if you can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call the module function `salt.cmd` you should also pass the required kwarg `with_pillar` to enable rendering the pillars as mentioned on the official [doc](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/runners/all/salt.runners.salt.html#salt.runners.salt.cmd)

You also probably want to correct the arg to `pillar` instead of `pillars`

```
secret = runner.cmd(fun='salt.cmd', arg=['pillar.get', 'my_secret'],  kwargs={"with_pillar": True})
```

However, I won't prefer this approach for two reasons:

1. it assumes your saltmaster's `id` matches the minion id you targeted in your `top.sls`, which is very unlikely as the master's `id` is suffixed by `_master` with the `hostname` of the host it is running on (by default).
2. highly cumbersome and is expensive. Why? because not only it first invokes the runner client which then calls the runner `salt` module, which later invokes the `pillar` module finally!

A better approach would be to import and use the `pillar` module directly as below and save a lot of expensive operations:

```
import salt.pillar
import salt.runner
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

runner = salt.runner.Runner(__opts__)

master_id = "my_saltmaster"
grains = None # specify any grain if required to render your top.sls

# Load required pillars
# deepcopy because we don't want to modify the actual __opts__
opts = copy.deepcopy(__opts__)
opts['pillar'] = salt.pillar.get_pillar(
    opts,
    grains,
    master_id,
    saltenv=opts['saltenv'],
    pillarenv=opts.get('pillarenv')).compile_pillar()

# extract required secret key from the pillar
my_secret = opts['pillar'].get('my_secret', None)
log.info(f"my_secret = {my_secret}")
```

Read more about the `pillar` module code [here](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/127a32e4806e1e186b80afaf60762ebcbc211ef5/salt/pillar/__init__.py#L39) :)

Comment: Genius! Amazing. Worked like a charm